# Adding dimensions to scipy sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I wish to add a dimension to a sparse matrix. In numpy it's simply a matter of doing `[:,None]`. I tried `reshape` and `resize` without any success.

Here's some dummy data:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
col = [0,0,0,1,1,1] 
row = [0,1,2,0,1,2] 
a = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
a.reshape((3,2,1))
```

The last line gives the error: `ValueError: matrix shape must be two-dimensional`. Doing `resize` instead gives the error `ValueError: shape must be a 2-tuple of positive integers`.

In my particular case I also need to reshape it to `(3,1,2)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Scipy sparse matrices are always 2d.  There's no adding or removing dimensions!

Comment: First line in the `scipy sparse` docs: **SciPy 2-D sparse matrix package for numeric data.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.sparse` can only handle 2d arrays. You might want to look into [pydata/sparse](https://github.com/pydata/sparse) which looks to handle n-dimensional sparse data while following the array interface. At the moment, it has fewer types of arrays and will have some performance issues, but is being actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
col = [0,0,0,1,1,1] 
row = [0,1,2,0,1,2] 
a = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
a.reshape((3,2))
```